# I am trying to run a java file and I got this error

Tags: java

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 24: C:/Users/herbw/OneDrive/?? ??/Files/Study/Programming/Java/Practice
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I got this error while I was trying to run a java file

I am a beginner so can I get an easy solution to this problem

Comment: You need to post your code. This is just an error message stating some illegal symbol in your class file somewhere.

Comment: Check the `Paths`, and to repair your code please share the it. I'm just guessing and think the following will be helpful : `Paths.get(getClass().getResource("FILE_NAME").toURI())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java program can't recognize the Path Name `C:/Users/herbw/OneDrive/?? ??/Files/Study/Programming/Java/Practice`
You need to change the `?? ??` part to English path names.